# SQL - Nested Select in From claus with Count

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

When I use the following code (it is from an Oracle guy and he says there is no reason for it not to work...) I am notified that there is incorrect syntax located at the last ')'.  Any idea how I can change this to be "SQL Appropriate"?  My thoughts are that it is not liking the last select statement.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    CPINInvest 
where 
    [Case ID||] not in 
        (
        select [Case ID||] 
        from 
            (
            select [Case ID||], count(*) 
            from CPINComm140 
            where [Role CD||]='PRI||' 
            group by [Case ID||]   
            having count(*)=1
            )
        )
```

Comment: Do you really have column names with pipe symbols at the end? That is weird. Or is it supposed to be an operator (in Oracle it signifies string concatenation)?

Comment: Unfortunately yes...we have columns with double pipe at the end :(  Not my design, not my choice, not my preference lol  We are populating these tables which will be used to populate an Oracle database and the developers chose the double pipe to signify the end of a column.

Comment: Offtopic: Double pipe to signify the end of a column. That's like the most hilarious thing I've ever heard considering database-design patterns :D

Comment: @KamilG. - clearly someone miss-understood a delimiter in an exported file vs a column name.

Comment: @Hogan exactly my thinking, but still made my day. EOT :)

Comment: @KamilG. - "Well the requirement said to end all the fields with ||"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be shortened.

```
select * from CPINInvest 
where [Case ID||] not in (
        select [Case ID||]
        from CPINComm140 
        where [Role CD||]='PRI||' 
        group by [Case ID||] 
        having count(*)=1
    );
```

But seriously, pipes in fieldnames? Yuk!

The reason why the original query would fail is:
1) the count(*) needs an alias. For example [total]
2) tsql has that odd requirement that some subqueries require an alias

Comment: Works like a charm!  Thanks.

Comment: fairly sure that 1) is not a thing -- blank column names are allowed in SQLServer (as are column names with || in them) -- and 2) was the problem.

Comment: @Hogan Well, I tried it out [here](http://rextester.com/l/sql_server_online_compiler). Then can you explain why for example it gives an error when trying this: `declare @T table (id int);
insert into @T values (1),(2);
select * from (select id, count(*) from @T group by id) q;`

Answer (score 0):

sql likes you to give aliases to your sub-queries even if they are not used.  This will work but @LukStorms shorter version is better.

```
select * 
from CPINInvest 
where 
    [Case ID||] not in 
        (
        select [Case ID||] 
        from 
            (
            select [Case ID||], count(*) 
            from CPINComm140 
            where [Role CD||]='PRI||' 
            group by [Case ID||]   
            having count(*)=1
            ) x
        ) y
```

Comment: also whoever made those column names should be shot.  *seriously*

Comment: I 100% agree with you

Answer (score 0):

use the below query. You have forgot to add alias to the sub table.

```
select 
    * 
from 
    CPINInvest 
where 
    [Case ID||] not in 
        (
        select [Case ID||] 
        from 
            (
            select [Case ID||], count(*) 
            from CPINComm140 
            where [Role CD||]='PRI||' 
            group by [Case ID||]   
            having count(*)=1
            )t
        )
```

Comment: why exactly post the same answer I posted 5 minutes ago?